# Django conditional annotation using python variable

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql

Trying to figure out a way to use annotation depending of python variable condition check.

Example:

```
some_variable = 10000,50 #float

expenses_by_categories = (
            Category.objects.filter(transactions__operation="expenses")
            .annotate(
                expenses_sum=Sum('transactions__value', filter=Q(
                    transactions__date_created__month=datetime.date.today().month) & Q(
                    transactions__date_created__year=datetime.date.today().year)),
            )
            .annotate(
                percentage=Round(
                    ExpressionWrapper(
                    F('expenses_sum') / some_variable * 100, output_field=FloatField()
                    ), 2))
            .order_by('-percentage')
        )
```

It works as long as `some_variable` greater then 0 otherwise `zero devision exception` rised.
Is there is a way to carry out some checks inside annotation with such a logic:

```
if some_variable > 0:
    percentage = F('expenses_sum') / some_variable * 100
else:
    percentage = 0
```

Comment: You could use the expression form of if/else:
`percentage=( F('expenses_sum') / some_variable * 100) if some_variable > 0 else 0`

Comment: You could make `some_variable = VERY_SMALL` or `some_variable = GINORMOUS` in order to avoid the DB getting indigestion. The former returns hige values which you would have to reset in Python. The latter limits to the conditional value of zero if you have suitable rounding in place (a very small nonzero annotation is created).

Comment: @RossRogers was throwing an error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'as_sql'` but manage to make it work slightly modifying your code : `.annotate(
                percentage=Value(0) if expenses_this_month_sum == 0 else ExpressionWrapper((F('expenses_sum') / expenses_this_month_sum * 100), output_field=FloatField()))` but still looking for more Django native solution if exist.

Comment: @nigel222 I'm not getting your point completely without some examples as my Django experience still very limited.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Case` with `When` to avoid the zero division exception in the annotation.

```py
from django.db.models import Case, When

queryset.annotate(
    percentage=Round(
        Case(
            When(some_variable=0, then=0),
            default=ExpressionWrapper(F('expenses_sum') / some_variable * 100, output_field=FloatField()),
        ),
        2,
    )
)
```

[Conditional Expressions Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/)

Comment: I've work around this solution on very beginning but looks likes Django ORM don't allow to use non-field values in `When` as I always get exception: `Cannot resolve keyword 'some_variable' into field. Choices are: children, expenses_sum, id, image, level, lft, name, parent, parent_id, rght, slug, transactions, tree_id`. Whith your code either.